# Do I need to purchase addtional licenses to use Terminal Services RemoteApp on Windows SBS 2008?

Tags: windows, windows-terminal-services

I want to make a single application avail. via Terminal Services RemoteApp on a Server running Windows SBS 2008.

Do I need to purchase any additional licenses or does SBS 2008 come with some?

Answer (score 1):

"You cannot use a server that is running Windows SBS 2008 as a terminal server." from ms technet

However some versions come with licences for a 2nd server which you can run TS on.  You need to purchase TS Client Access Licence for each user.

Answer (score 1):

You cannto enable terminal services on an SBS 2008 server.  Even though the install will not fail you will receive error 800713D in Terminal Services Configuration when attempting to change the licensing mode from Remote Desktop for Administration to any other mode.  You also cannot buy licenses for terminal server under SBS 2008.

See [Can I Use Terminal Services in SBS 2008?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2008/09/26/can-i-use-terminal-services-in-sbs-2008.aspx)